# How to get selected colour from colour picker without clicking outside of popup

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi everyone I am using HTML input type="color" to display the color picker.
I want to get the selected color from the color picker without clicking outside of the popup.

for example

```
<input type="color" onchange="alert(this.value)">
```

Now I can get the selected color when I click outside of the picker only

But I want to get the color while clicking color from the inside of the picker (without clicking outside of the popup)

Thanks, Advance...

Comment: ```<input type="color" oninput="console.log(this.value)" />``` use oninput.

Comment: @ikhvjs Awesome it's working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) event handler instead of [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange).

```html
<input type="color" oninput="alert(this.value)">
```

Comment: have you checked the alert value with the value of selected color, i tried but it isn't working.

Comment: @HarshGundecha I have checked that alert value its coming selected color value checked in chrome Version 90.0.4430.212

Comment: @giridharan got it, i was testing after clicking on pencil icon, but it seems you were not looking for that, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to the input event, following your code like

```html
<div id="value"></div>
<input type="color" oninput="document.querySelector('#value').innerText= this.value">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use oninput attribute for the same

```js
function selectColor(color) {
  document.getElementById("selectedColor").innerText = color;
}
```

```html
<p id="selectedColor">select color</p>
<input type="color" oninput="selectColor(this.value)"/>
```